# FileNotFoundError with filepath that has whitespaces using ZipFile extract

Tags: python, path, python-zipfile

I have a zip file with this structure:

```
Report 
│
└───folder1
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
|       |
│       │file 1 2022.txt
│   
└───folder2
    │   file2.txt
```

And their relative file paths are as follows: `Report/folder1 / subfolder1 / file 1 2022.txt` and `Report/folder2/file2.txt`

I tried to extract the zip file to another destination using the following code:

```
with ZipFile(attachment_filepath, 'r') as z:
    z.extractall('Destination')
```

However, it gives me a `FileNotFoundError: [Winerror 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Report\\folder1 \\ subfolder1 '`

I can extract just `file2.txt` without any problems but trying to extract `file 1 2022.txt` gives me that error,presumably due to all the extra whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"folder1 "` (note the space) isn't the same as `"folder1"` (no space). When passing a path, it has to be the exact path. You can't add whitespace between path separators because the file system will assume you want a path name *with* spaces. Whatever put those spaces into the path is the problem.